# Has the behavior of `drop = FALSE` been changed in R version 4 without the documentation making note of that?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Forgetting to add `drop = FALSE` where you need it is one of the classic R frustrations. This issue is so well-known that the Tibble package has its replacement for data frames always pass `drop = FALSE` ([example](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#safe-subsetting)). Everything that I remember about R tells me for absolutely certain that data frames respect `drop = FALSE`. However, if I look at the documentation for `[` (Extract {base}), I find that it says:

> `drop` For matrices and arrays.

Notably, this does not mention data frames. Does this suggest that `drop` has been changed recently? My intuition, supported by the hyperlinked example about tibbles, insists that data frames respect the `drop` argument, but I can no longer find any documentation to support that.

Comment: Since `[` is a generic function, there is the `?\`[.data.frame\`` specific help page. The special behavior of `drop=` for data.frames is still there. There is a link to that page in the `See Also` section of the main `?Extract` help page.

Comment: @MrFlick Beat me to it. I've just finished posting my answer after rediscovering that fact moments after posting the question. Silly me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[` is a generic function. You wanted the documentation for `[.data.frame` (Extract.data.frame {base}).

> `drop` logical. If `TRUE` the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.